# Slickgrid keydown issue when pasting from Excel

Tags: javascript, jquery, slickgrid

I am using Slickgrid and I want to be able to copy and paste from Excel.

The sample I have found allows this
https://6pac.github.io/SlickGrid/examples/example-excel-compatible-spreadsheet.html
however, there is an issue I am experiencing (which can be seen in the example) and I think it is undesirable.

I have my cells editable, so basically, I single click into a cell and can type straightaway. I tab or cursor to another cell and again, I can type straight away.

With the example, I can't do that anymore. I have to double click before I can enter anything.

The relevant plugin that handles paste from Excel is https://github.com/6pac/SlickGrid/blob/master/plugins/slick.cellexternalcopymanager.js

I have found that if I comment line 63 on the above (_grid.focus()) then I get my single click and type, but then the paste doesn't work.

Actually, let me correct that... I have just tried again with the _grid.focus() commented out and I can single click and type and I can paste from Excel. (Now, I am not sure why I even need the _grid.focus())

I don't understand what the .focus() is doing so unfortunately, I am unable to fix it myself. It appears the .focus() is going off into the JQuery libraries, though why it should break the regular click and type, I don't know.

Do I even need line 63 now? I am only (at the moment) ever going to paste into Slickgrid, not select from.

Any direction would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Edited] There are a couple of grid options that control the experience here.

If `autoEdit` is off, you need to double click the cell to get into edit mode (a single click just selects the cell). If it's on, a single click will select and edit a cell.

If `asyncEditorLoading` is on, then the editors fire up immediately and, for example, in a text editor the text in the cell will start off fully selected (otherwise you require a second click to select the text).

Note however, with `autoEdit` on, you can't select regions of the grid to cut and paste. This is an issue that will have to be dealt with in the grid code at some point (I am one of the project maintainers).

Here are the final options:

```
var options = {
  editable: true,
  enableAddRow: true,
  enableCellNavigation: true,
  asyncEditorLoading: true,
  autoEdit: true
};
```

Comment: In this case, this is not the problem. My autoEdit is set to true, and I have put a breakpoint to ensure it is still set to true when I attempt to edit the cell. I have put a breakpoint on the _grid.focus() and the line after and then in the Console, I type...

_grid.getOptions().autoEdit and on both breakpoints, the response is true.

Comment: In the example https://6pac.github.io/SlickGrid/examples/example-excel-compatible-spreadsheet.html, I can see that the option is set to false, I put a breakpoint on line 204 in the html, and changed the option to true. I then checked at the _grid.focus() and it was still true, but it exhibits the same problem.

Comment: I'm trying to clarify what the sequence of events is. When I set autoEdit=true, I can't select an area in Slickgrid any more. However pasting from Excel is unaffected. Also, with autoEdit on, you can go into the editor with a single click but it takes another click to hilight the text in the cell. So can I confirm you are saying, that *without* modifying anything, you (1) can edit the cells with a single click, (2) paste from Excel, then (3) can only edit the cells with a double click?

Comment: In the example code, I can't do number 1. I want to be able to... 1. Single click in the cell to be able edit. 2. Paste from Excel. 3. Single click to be able to edit. In my own code, if I comment line 63 (_grid.focus()) in the slick.cellexternalcopymanager.js, then I get all 3, but should I be editting this plugin? Is there a workaround (even modifying the plugin), that will allow the plugin to work as it should? (removing _grid.focus() stops the group cell copy from Slickgrid)

Comment: After some investigation, I suspect the grid option ```asyncEditorLoading: true``` will do what you want. However, with autoEdit set to true, you can't select regions of the grid for cut and paste. This may no matter to you, but it's an issue that will have to be dealt with in the grid code at some point.

Comment: That seems to have worked, thank you. If you want to edit your answer, I will mark it as solved. The only thing that doesn't work, is to select a number of cells in Slickgrid to be able to copy back to Excel, but I am not too concerned about that at present.

Comment: i have summarised the comments in the answer